# How to perform ASE-256-CBC encrypt and decrypt on Android NDK c++?

Tags: android, c++, encryption, android-ndk, aes

I want to perform AES-256-CBC encryption and decryption on Android NDK c++. and i am very new to it. I have the encrypted data obtain from various input and need to decrypt it. and also i want to prevent the expose of encryption key and some additional twist while decryption. as android apk can be easily de-compiled. I tried to add OPENSSL into NDK by adding libcrypto.a and libssl.a into ndk but it says AES_cbc_encrypt not found.

This is my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.2)

# Declares and names the project.

project("myapplication")

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
             native-lib

             # Sets the library as a shared library.
             SHARED

             # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
             native-lib.cpp )

find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
              log-lib

              # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
              # you want CMake to locate.
              log )


target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                       native-lib

                       # Links the target library to the log library
                       # included in the NDK.
                       ${log-lib} )
```

If anyone have any idea on how to get this work done. Then i really appreciate it.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you use `C`, look at `mbedtls` in here. I also used this library for my android app.

`https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbedtls`

1. Download `mbedtls-development.zip` from `https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbedtls` or click this link: https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbedtls/archive/refs/heads/development.zip
2. Extract `mbedtls-development.zip` in your drive and then copy `*.c files` from `\mbedtls-development\library\` folder to your android `\app\src\main\cpp\mbedtls\*.c`
   and copy `*.h` files from `\mbedtls-development\include\mbedtls\` folder to your android `\app\src\main\cpp\mbedtls\*.h`
3. Rename all files from `*.c` to `*.cpp`
4. Update your `CMakeList.txt` as bellow.
5. Look at here how to use AES CBC: https://tls.mbed.org/kb/how-to/encrypt-with-aes-cbc

Example:

native-lib.cpp

```
#include "../../../mbedtls/config.h"
#include "../../../mbedtls/aes.h"

void encWithAes() {
    
        
    // keys 32 bytes
    unsigned char key[] = {0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08,
                           0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08,
                           0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08,
                           0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08};

    // initial vector 16 bytes
    unsigned char iv[] = {0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08,
                          0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08};


    unsigned char input [] = {0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08};
    unsigned char output[128];
        

    mbedtls_aes_context aes;
    mbedtls_aes_init(&aes);
    mbedtls_aes_setkey_enc(&aes, key, 256);
    
    // this is cbc encrypted with key 32 bytes and initial vector 16 bytes
    mbedtls_aes_crypt_cbc(&aes, MBEDTLS_AES_ENCRYPT, 16, iv, input, output);        

}
```

`CMakeList.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

option(USE_SHARED_MBEDTLS_LIBRARY "Build mbed TLS shared library." ON)

set(
        src_mbedtls
        mbedtls/aes.cpp
        #mbedtls/aesni.cpp
        #mbedtls/arc4.cpp
        #mbedtls/aria.cpp
        #mbedtls/asn1parse.cpp
        #mbedtls/asn1write.cpp
        #mbedtls/base64.cpp
        #mbedtls/bignum.cpp
        #mbedtls/blowfish.cpp
        #mbedtls/camellia.cpp
        #mbedtls/ccm.cpp
        #mbedtls/chacha20.cpp
        #mbedtls/chachapoly.cpp
        #mbedtls/cipher.cpp
        #mbedtls/cipher_wrap.cpp
        #mbedtls/cmac.cpp
        #mbedtls/ctr_drbg.cpp
        #mbedtls/des.cpp
        #mbedtls/dhm.cpp
        #mbedtls/ecdh.cpp
        #mbedtls/ecdsa.cpp
        #mbedtls/ecjpake.cpp
        #mbedtls/ecp.cpp
        #mbedtls/ecp_curves.cpp
        #mbedtls/entropy.cpp
        #mbedtls/entropy_poll.cpp
        mbedtls/error.cpp
        #mbedtls/gcm.cpp
        #mbedtls/havege.cpp
        #mbedtls/hkdf.cpp
        #mbedtls/hmac_drbg.cpp
        #mbedtls/md.cpp
        #mbedtls/md2.cpp
        #mbedtls/md4.cpp
        #mbedtls/md5.cpp
        #mbedtls/md_wrap.cpp
        #mbedtls/memory_buffer_alloc.cpp
        #mbedtls/nist_kw.cpp
        #mbedtls/oid.cpp
        #mbedtls/padlock.cpp
        #mbedtls/pem.cpp
        #mbedtls/pk.cpp
        #mbedtls/pk_wrap.cpp
        #mbedtls/pkcs12.cpp
        #mbedtls/pkcs5.cpp
        #mbedtls/pkparse.cpp
        #mbedtls/pkwrite.cpp
        mbedtls/platform.cpp
        mbedtls/platform_util.cpp
        #mbedtls/poly1305.cpp
        #mbedtls/ripemd160.cpp
        #mbedtls/rsa.cpp
        #mbedtls/rsa_internal.cpp
        #mbedtls/sha1.cpp
        #mbedtls/sha256.cpp
        #mbedtls/sha512.cpp
        #mbedtls/threading.cpp
        #mbedtls/timing.cpp
        #mbedtls/version.cpp
        #mbedtls/version_features.cpp
        #mbedtls/xtea.cpp
        #mbedtls/certs.cpp
        #mbedtls/pkcs11.cpp
        #mbedtls/x509.cpp
        #mbedtls/x509_create.cpp
        #mbedtls/x509_crl.cpp
        #mbedtls/x509_crt.cpp
        #mbedtls/x509_csr.cpp
        #mbedtls/x509write_crt.cpp
        #mbedtls/x509write_csr.cpp
        #mbedtls/debug.cpp
        #mbedtls/net_sockets.cpp
        #mbedtls/ssl_cache.cpp
        #mbedtls/ssl_ciphersuites.cpp
        #mbedtls/ssl_cli.cpp
        #mbedtls/ssl_cookie.cpp
        #mbedtls/ssl_srv.cpp
        #mbedtls/ssl_ticket.cpp
        #mbedtls/ssl_tls.cpp
)
set(
        src_native-lib
        native-lib.cpp  
)
#
add_library(            # mbedtls
        mbedtls         #   sets the name of the library.
        SHARED          #   sets the library as a shared library.
        ${src_mbedtls}  #   provides a relative path to your source file(s).
        )
add_library(
        native-lib  
        SHARED
        ${src_native-lib}
        mbedtls
)
#
find_library(
        log-lib          # Sets the name of the path variable.
        log              # Specifies the name of the NDK library that you want CMake to locate.
)
#
target_link_libraries(   # mbedtls
        mbedtls          #  Specifies the target library.
        ${log-lib}       #  Links the target library to the log library included in the NDK.
        )
target_link_libraries(
        native-lib       
        mbedtls
        ${log-lib}
)
```

Comment: can you tell me in more detail what am i suppose to copy from programs and where i should copy these into my project?

Comment: I've added an answer, hope it helps.

Comment: as i have renamed aes.c to aes.cpp and later doing #include mbedtls/aes.h . it says mbedtls/aes.h not found. I have a question on this as we are only copying content of library folder, what about files in include folder. they are missing in our android project

Comment: #include "../../../mbedtls/config.h"
#include "../../../mbedtls/aes.h"

Comment: look at CMakeList.txt, I am assuming you wrote the aes procedure inside native-lib.cpp

Comment: Where should i unzip mbedtls-development.zip?

Comment: i have copied all file with *.c and *.h from library into */cpp/mbedtls/*
and rename all *.c to *.cpp, there is no file with name aes.h in */cpp/mbedtls/*.

Comment: unzip `mbedtls-development.zip` to everywhere in your drive , then open `mbedtls-development` folder (result of extracted). Open `library` folder then `copy` *.c and *.h files  to `\app\src\main\cpp\mbedtls\`

Comment: look at headers in \mbedtls-development\include\mbedtls\*.h

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234799/discussion-between-krishna-acharya-and-sabrina-n).